# Data population on asp GridView during population of data table

Tags: .net, vb.net, gridview, data-binding

My VB.net application has to fetch a large amount of data and populate the GridView. Now the data population is happening after getting full data to data table. I want to know is it possible to display the data in GridView when ever one row is added to the data table?..

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have a routine/method which is continuously checking for updates to the Data Source. Once you receive the update, you would need to call the DataBind() method again on the grid.

UPDATE:
GridView control will show what's is in DataSource, so you need to modify the DataSource.

One of the possible way could be using asynchronous calls from your Server Side C# code and on the Callback you can reset the DataSource Property.

If you are flexible then you can also try Knockout binding using MVVM pattern, have a HTML table bound to [knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html) Observable Array in View Model.

Comment: No it is not like that. once I trier the data population it is going to get data from 232 DBs. It is taking a long time. I want to populate data once one DB is completed.